# 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined to page' how to fix it

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, google-tag-manager

I found a problem on the console on all pages I have the same error Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined at.

I try to fix it with tag asistant but there is no errors and any solution for this.

I don't know if this error has anything to do with the site's drop in traffic?